# Overriding Hydra config with experiment

Tags: fb-hydra, omegaconf

I'm working through [this Hydra doc example](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/) to override the main config with an experiment config. I'm trying to override `main` with `experiment` and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

The error I get is:

```
Exception has occurred: ConstructorError
while constructing a mapping
  in "/home/ghb/projects/aisc/embeddings_and_difficulty/configs_hydra/experiment/experiment.yaml", line 2, column 1
found duplicate key main
  in "/home/ghb/projects/aisc/embeddings_and_difficulty/configs_hydra/experiment/experiment.yaml", line 9, column 1
  File "/home/ghb/projects/aisc/embeddings_and_difficulty/runner.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a mapping
  in "/home/ghb/projects/aisc/embeddings_and_difficulty/configs_hydra/experiment/experiment.yaml", line 2, column 1
found duplicate key main
  in "/home/ghb/projects/aisc/embeddings_and_difficulty/configs_hydra/experiment/experiment.yaml", line 9, column 1
```

Folder structure:

```
configs
   |--- experiment
    |--- experiment.yaml
   |--- main
    |--- general.yaml
    |--- debug.yaml
   config.yaml
```

My `config.yaml`:

```
defaults:
  - main: general
  - experiment: experiment
```

My `experiment.yaml`:

```
# @package _global_
defaults:
  - override /main: debug

main:
  TRAINING:
    BACKBONE:
      MAX_EPOCH: 20
```

My `general.yaml`:

```
main:
  TRAINING:
    BACKBONE:
      MAX_EPOCH: 200
```

My `debug.yaml`:

```
main:
  TRAINING:
    BACKBONE:
      MAX_EPOCH: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error normally appears when Hydra loads a YAML file with a duplicate key. I this case `configs_hydra/experiment/experiment.yaml`.
The file content you provided here does not have a duplicate `main` key, but I suspect your actual file does.
If it doesn't, please provide a zip file with a minimal repro.

Comment: Indeed you were right! Many thanks :)